# How to get data from SQL and write it in textbox?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need a help.

I searched and I tried a lot but I am too bad to make it work on my project by myself.

This is code for button-Seek. I want to make Seek-button to fill textbox by respective data.

```
    private void SeekClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TBCusNumber.Text != "")
        {
            string Number = TBCusNumber.Text;

            var Conn = new SqlConnection();
            Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Settings.DataBase"].ConnectionString;

            var Cmd = new SqlCommand();
            Cmd.Connection = Conn;
            Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CustomerList WHERE CustomerNumber = " + Number;

            var DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "CustomerList");

            CusView.DataSource = DataSet;
            CusView.DataMember = "CustomerList";
        }
    }
```

And This is the data table.
[image]

This is what happens when I put 3 in the text box and press Seek-button.
[image]

So here, I want all text boxes to be filled by the data which I searched.

Comment: Please provide codes as text here not images...

Comment: changed as text

Comment: [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Tip, not related to your problem; `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are all `IDisposable`, so should be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get only one row for the query right?

So give like that,

```
txtFirstName.Text = DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
txtLasttName.Text = DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
```

Like this you need to assign the values to the respective text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problem need to fix.

1. You forget to open the connection with DB,add `Conn.Open();` before you excute sql command.
2. You need to add parameter to prevention `SQL Injection`
3. Please use `using` it will help you to use external resources to return the memory.

when the `DataSet` be filled you can get the data then fill in textbox

You can follow like this.

```
private void SeekClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TBCusNumber.Text != "")
    {
        string Number = TBCusNumber.Text;

        using (var Conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Settings.DataBase"].ConnectionString;
            using (var Cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                Cmd.Connection = Conn;
                Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CustomerList WHERE CustomerNumber = @Number";

                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Number);
                //You miss to add Conn.Open()
                Conn.Open();
                using (var DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd))
                {
                    DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();
                    DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "CustomerList");
                    CusView.DataSource = DataSet;
                    CusView.DataMember = "CustomerList";

                    //when the DataSet be filled you can get the data then fill in textbox
                    txt_firstName.Text = DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But all of them are corrections about his code, how about the answer of his question ?, he want to write data into text boxes.

Comment: yes that is my question. but thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Ok I miss you really question, my fail:( .Could you tell me about your table scheme from `CustomerList ` ? because I need to know the binding data name

Comment: thank you for your corrections. questions is answered.

Comment: @JungminKoo Ok I see :)